# Wait until execution of Perl script finished inside php script

Tags: php, perl

I am trying to execute perl script inside php script. Although it is running but only for short duration.
How to increase the time-limit so that the execution of perl script is finished until the final php script  is called of ?

I am running php script on the localhost.

Here is the code :

```
<?php

$maxChildren = 1;  
$pids = array();
$pid = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid) { // Parent

    if ($pid < 0) {
        // Unable to fork process, handle error here
        continue;
    } else {
        $pids[$pid] = $pid;
    }

} else {

    exec("perl -f script.pl  ");
    exit(0);

}

while(pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1);

?>
```

Comment: You don't need a while loop for pcntl_waitpid.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to increase the time limit  until execution of perl script is finished inside php script while using it in localhost.

Comment: There shouldn't be a time limit if you are executing it in CLI.  How are you executing it and what error are you receiving?

Comment: Thanks for replying. So in browser I am running by using http://localhost/hello.php. Normally in command line my perl script execution is finished in 10 min . But here its getting finished only in 1 min without completion and without error.

Comment: @Devon: Unless you want to seem like a teenager, *"executed from the command line"* is fine

Comment: @Borodin why does referring to the acronym for command line interface make me seem like a teenager?

Comment: @Devon: Same reason stuff lyk this duz. U shudnt do it if u want 2 b t8n serious

Comment: @Borodin, that makes no sense.  An acronym is a legitimate shortening of a phrase, lyk is just a misspelled word.  It'd be like using USA instead of United States... please troll elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've over-complicated the problem. Unless I'm missing something, your entire code can be replaced by a single line

```
<?php
exec("perl -f script.pl  ");
?>
```

as this will have the same effect as forking and then immediately waiting for the child process to finish.

To avoid the page timing out before the perl script is finished, simply add `set_time_limit(0)` before calling exec:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
exec("perl -f script.pl  ");
?>
```

Comment: You can remove the trailing spaces, too (and I'm skeptical whether `-f` is needed).

Comment: Well spotted, my apologies for copypasting the line from the original post!

Comment: As Already I  did tried your simple suggestion. But it did't work. That is why  I switched on to forking.

Comment: What didn't work about it? If an `exec` call by itself doesn't work, I don't see how the same `exec` call inside a forked child process would work either. Have you tried using absolute paths to both `perl` and `script.pl`?

Comment: So in both cases (forking and without forking) the php script is working, but the execution of perl script is getting finished in 1 min while using it on localhost but in command line perl script its taking 10 min to complete the whole process . So I need to increase time limit  for the localhost.

Comment: @Keiji so when I am setting time limit for 10 min but it is getting finished few seconds. Any idea what can be the problem in it ?